# Socket connection refused error in python

Tags: python, python-sockets

I am trying to write a simple socket application in python.

In my code below, however, I am getting error at line 4 that says

> Socket error errno 111 connection refused

Could anyone help me out?

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()

sock.connect((host, 12345))
sock.setblocking(1)    
    
data = "Hello Python\n" *10*1024*1024 
assert sock.send(data)
```

Comment: Do you have another script or program running on the same machine, that is accepting socket connections on the same port number?

Answer (score 0):

If its Windows machine, try `netstat -ano | findStr "12345"` command in command prompt.

- If above command provided any results, then see which processId is using the port and you can use different port number (or) kill the processId in task manager.
- If above command doesn't provide any hit, ugly approach is try with different port number.